# Variance of the sum of multiple random number generators

Tags: variance, random-variable, random-generation

Let's assume I have "n" random number generators, each one has a different variance value, but has the same mean value, zero.

If I generate "n" random numbers with these generators, and sum all of them for an output in an iteration, after many iteration steps, I will get an array as a result. What will be the variance of this output? What is the logic?

For example; 4 random number generators which of variance values are "16","25","36","49". What is the total variance if I sum all of them?
[image]

Comment: Assuming the RNGs are independent (they needn't be and you haven't stated anything about this), *variances add.*  You can find this fact used and demonstrated in a very great number of threads here.  Try [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22variances+add%22), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your $n$ random number generators are like $n$ random variables. The [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of a sum of random variables $X$ and $Y$ is

$$
\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) + 2 \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)
$$

Assuming that the variables are independent, the covariance is zero, so it reduces to the sum of variances.

Comment: This is correct but incomplete.  To see why, consider a version of this question where the RNGs do not all have the same mean.  A complete answer needs to take that into consideration.

Comment: @whuber Common mean is not needed, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Suppose you have two RNGs, one of which is uniform on $[0,1]$ and the other on $[100,101].$  Output one value from each to obtain a two-element output.  What do suppose the variance of that array will be?  I see there are two possible interpretations of the question: one would be the sampling variance (under iteration); the other is the variance of the output.  Now I recognize you answered the first, but I originally made the second interpretation.  The edit to the question favors your interpretation.  But in your interpretation you can find zillions of answers here--why not close as a dup?

Comment: @whuber but the question asks explicitly about the variance of their sum.

Comment: My results are here. Var(X+Y+Z+A) ~= 487 and Var(X)+Var(Y)+Var(Z)+Var(A) ~= 126. So the difference is from Cov(i,j) values, right?

Comment: @FarukUNAL question is if they are correlated or not. This would answer it.

Comment: @whuber Could you explain two different interpretations? Which approach is right for sampling variance? And which approach is right for output variance? You can just give me keywords to study :) you don't have to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If they are normally distributed, the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of the variance of the summands.</s> As pointed out in the comments of my answer, this is not true, i.e. normally distributed variables are not required, but independence is. This can be checked by the following program

```
import numpy as np

mu, n, vars = 0, 1000000, [16, 25, 36, 49]
sums = np.zeros(n)
for var in vars:
    sums += np.random.normal(mu, var ** 0.5, n)
print(f'sum of variances = {sum(vars)}')
print(f'variance of sums = {np.var(sums):.2f}')
```

which prints something like

```
sum of variances = 126
variance of sums = 126.22
```

Comment: They don't need to be normally distributed.

Comment: Additivity of variance has nothing to do with Normal distributions.  It has everything to do with (1) independence and (2) having a common mean.  (Otherwise, the variance of those means contributes the overall variance.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Tim and whuber. I'll try to be more careful next time.

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake in one of my first posts here :-).  In the present case, although (1) clearly is important, I view (2) as being of the greatest interest.

Comment: @whuber I have adjusted my answer correspondingly.

Comment: Excuse me, my result a bit different; var_RESULT = var(out.res) is 487.7499 and
var_TOTAL = (var_RNG_1+var_RNG_2+var_RNG_3+var_RNG_4) is 126.9762. What is the difference?